# what is IPC performance?

Tags: linux, performance, cluster

I saw material illustrating a 6% core single thread IPC performance increase from one generation of some hardware to the next. Does it mean that the number of instructions per cycle increases by 6%? What is exactly IPC performance?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_cycle, http://www.anandtech.com/show/9483/intel-skylake-review-6700k-6600k-ddr4-ddr3-ipc-6th-generation/9